# MVC 3 Compare Attribute Not Working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am working on an MVC app, which has a registration form where I want to use the Compare, Required and Regex attributes for email validation. The user has to enter their email address, and then confirm email address, I want to use the Compare attribute to ensure they enter the same thing. This is my model;

```
[RegularExpression(@"<REGEX IS HERE>", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid e-mail address")]
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

[Compare("EmailAddress", ErrorMessage = "The email and confirmation email do not match.")]
[RegularExpression(@"<REGEX IS HERE>", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid e-mail address")]        
[Required]        
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]        
[Display(Name = "Confirm Email")]        
public string ConfirmEmailAddress { get; set; }
```

All the other validation i.e. required / regex works fine, but it doesn't work client side for the Compare, it is working as when the form posts it comes back and errors.

I have read many articles saying there is a bug in jquery.validate.unobtrusive and jquery1.5.1 but whatever I do doesn't resolve the issue.

I am pulling my hair out here, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting into fancy validation anyway, you might consider grabbing [MVC Foolproof Validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) off of NuGet.  It has its own "EqualTo" attribute that you might have more luck with.

(On a side note, you probably don't need to regex check the confirmation address.)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that other attributes are intefering.. all you really need is the Compare and Display attributes.  Required, Regex, DataType are all superfluous, because you already have those fields on the primary, and the compare will fail if it doesn't match the primary.

Another idea is to download the MvcContrib package, and use the Email attribute that automatically does Email validation, rather than use the Regex.